# Program does not recognize value as a valid variable value?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The program I am trying to create involves writing a method called monster_fight(monster1,monster2) to have the two monsters "Fight". However I am having one issue retrieving the damage value stored in each of the monster object dictionaries named 'self.attacks'.

I am trying to retrieve a value from dictionary 'monster1.attacks' to reduce the hp of the monster2 object. However with the current code I have in place, the program does not recognize the value of the keys when I call the dictionary. Can anybody show what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

```
class Monster():
    def __init__(self, name, max_hp = 20, hp=20):
        self.name = name
        self.type = type
        self.current_hp = max_hp
        self.attacks = {'wait': 0}
        self.possible_attacks = {'sneak_attack': 1,
                                'slash': 2,
                                'ice_storm': 3,
                                'fire_storm': 3,
                                'whirlwind': 3,
                                'earthquake': 2,
                                'double_hit': 4,
                                'wait': 0}
        self.exp = 0 


    def add_attack(self, attack_name):
        if attack_name in self.possible_attacks:
            self.attacks[attack_name] = self.possible_attacks.get(attack_name)
            return True
        else:
            return False
        if attack_name in self.attacks:
            return False

    def remove_attack(self, attack_name):
        if attack_name in self.attacks:
            self.attacks.pop(attack_name)
            if len(self.attacks) == 0:
                self.attacks['wait'] = 0
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def win_fight(self):
        self.exp += 5
        self.current_hp = self.max_hp

    def lose_fight(self):
        self.exp += 1
        self.current_hp = self.max_hp

def monster_fight(monster1,monster2):
    round1 = 0
    moves1 = []
    moves2 = []
    list1 = []
    list2 = []
    for i in monster1.attacks:
        values = ''
        values = monster1.attacks.get(i)
        list1.append(values)
    for i in range(0,len(monster2.attacks)):
        values = monster2.attacks.get(i)
        list2.append(values)


    while monster1.current_hp > 0 or monster2.current_hp > 0:
        round1 += 1
        monster1_attack = int(monster1.attacks[list1[(round1-1)%len(list1)]])
        monster2.current_hp -= monster1_attack
        moves1.append(list1[(round1-1)%len(list1)])

        monster2_attack= monster2.attacks[list2[(round1-1)%len(list2)]]
        monster1.current_hp -= monster2_attack
        moves2.append(list2[(round1-1)%len(list2)])

    if monster1.current_hp <= 0:
        monster1.lose_fight()
        monster2.win_fight()
        return round1, monster2.name, moves2
    elif monster1.current_hp <= 0:
        monster2.lose_fight()
        monster1.win_fight()
        return round1,monster1.name, moves1
    else:
        return -1,"None","None"



a = Monster("a", 9)
b = Monster("b", 9)
a.add_attack("ice_storm")
b.add_attack("ice_storm")
b.remove_attack("wait")
a.remove_attack("wait")
round1, winner, moves = monster_fight(a, b)
print(round1)
print(winner.name)
print(moves)
```

```
monster1_attack = int(monster1.attacks[list1[(round1-1)%len(list1)]])
KeyError: 3
```

Comment: When your question includes an error like this, it's often very helpful to include the complete traceback (and ensure that the line numbers reported in the error match the line numbers in the code you've included in your question). This makes it much easier for someone else to figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, let's see.  You're calling:

```
monster1_attack = int(monster1.attacks[list1[(round1-1)%len(list1)]])
```

`monster1` is a `Monster` object, created from:

```
a = Monster("a", 9)
a.add_attack("ice_storm")
a.remove_attack("wait")
```

So `monster1.attacks` looks like:

```
{
  'ice_storm': 3,
}
```

You're trying to access that dictionary using key dervied from `list1[(round1-1)%len(list1)]`.

`list1` is set here:

```
for i in monster1.attacks:
   values = ''
   values = monster1.attacks.get(i)
   list1.append(values)
```

After the above code runs, `list1` is a list that looks like:

```
[3]
```

(Because you ask for `monster1.attacks.get(i)`, which will return the *value* associated with key `i`.)

So when you ask for `list1[(round1-1)%len(list1)]`, you get the value `3`, which means you're asking for `monster1.attacks[3]`.

There is no key named `3` in `monster1.attacks`. As we saw earlier, the only key is `ice_storm` which has the *value* `3`. It looks like you're trying to figure out the damage that `monster1`'s attack will do.  That is actually what you have in `list1`, so in theory you could just write:

```
monster1_attack = list1[(round1-1)%len(list1)]
monster2.current_hp -= monster1_attack
```

I think your logic here may be a bit convoluted. You should probably think carefully about exactly what you're trying to accomplish and try to simplify your code with that goal in mind. Using the Python debugger to see the value of your variables prior to the error -- or using `print` statements to accomplish the same thing -- can help diagnose this sort of problem.

Comment: Looks like I was overthinking it a little bit, but that worked perfectly. Thank you

Comment: For a follow up question, for my 'moves1' and 'moves2' lists, I have to store the name of the attack rather than the value of the attack i.e. store 'ice_storm' instead of '3'.  Is there a clean way to do this or would I have to create a seperate function to call from the monster1.attacks dict?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow that question.  I think your best bet is to open a new question. Post your updated code there, along with a good description of what you're trying to accomplish, along with a description of what parts of your current code are giving you trouble.